# Docker building deleted modules from cache

Tags: docker, caching, module, docker-compose, azerothcore

I've built [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) using docker and am having issues stopping docker from building deleted modules from presumably the cache

docker build:

```
[ 16%] Built target authserver
[ 37%] Built target game
Scanning dependencies of target scripts
[ 37%] Building CXX object
src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/__/__/__/GenLoader.cpp.o
[ 38%] Building CXX object
src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/__/__/__/modules/mod-npc-buffer/src/npc_buffer.cpp.o
[ 38%] Linking CXX static library libscripts.a
[ 98%] Built target scripts
```

I've also cleared `azerothcore-wotlk\docker\build\cache\src` of the module and any files referencing it

Comment: have you tried deleting the directory `azerothcore-wotlk\docker\build\cache` entirely?

Comment: clearing the cache didn't do the trick, rebuilt the wrong one wops.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the Docker build after I had moved some things around and needed to recompile. I ended up using:

```
bin/acore-docker-remove-build-cache
```

(located at: [azerothcore/bin/acore-docker-remove-build-cache](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/bin/acore-docker-remove-build-cache)) and that cleared it all up for me and allowed for a clean re-build.

This is equivalent of manually removing everything that is inside:

```
azerothcore-wotlk\docker\build\cache
```

Comment: I did try running that, although no luck